# Rust:axum implement Handler

Tags: rust, extract, handler, rust-axum

I have a Server struct like so

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Server {
  address: String,
  rpc: RpcHandler,
  state: AppState,
}

impl Server {
  pub fn new(address: &str, rpc: RpcHandler, state: AppState) -> Self {
    Self {
      address: address.to_string(),
      rpc,
      state,
    }
  }

  pub async fn start(&self) -> Result<()> {
    let app = Router::new()
      .route("/", get(handlers::status_handler))
      .route("/json", post(self.clone()))
      .with_state(self.state.clone())
      .layer(middleware::map_response(handlers::response_handler))
      .layer(middleware::from_fn(middlewares::context_resolver));

    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind(&self.address).await.unwrap();

    println!("Listening on {}", &listener.local_addr().unwrap());

    axum::serve(listener, app.into_make_service())
      .await
      .unwrap();

    Ok(())
  }
}
```

Explanation:

- `address` : URL the Server will be bound on
- `rpc`: RpcHandler Struct which contains Rpc commands the server will respond to
- `state`: App state (DB Connection ...)

I've implemented Handler to this struct like so :

```rust
impl Handler<Request<Body>, AppState> for Server {
  type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Response<Body>> + Send>>;

  fn call(self, req: Request<Body>, state: AppState) -> Self::Future {
    Box::pin(async move {
      // For Test
      let result: JsonResult = Ok(Json(json!({ "message": "Hello world" })));

      match result {
        Ok(json_response) => json_response.into_response(),
        Err(error) => {
          let error_response = Json(json!({ "error": error.to_string() })).into_response();
          error_response
        }
      }
      /*
        Expected Behavior

        // Extract Context
        // Extract Body -> RpcCommand({ command: String, params: (Some Json) })
      
        let rpc_request = // Extracted from body
        let rpc_command = match &self.rpc.get_command(rpc_request.name) {
          Some(command) => &command.execute(context, state, rpc_request.params).await;
          None => // Send CommandNotFoundError
        };
      */
    })
  }
}
```

I have problems extracting the context (which is resolved by the `context_resolver` middleware and implements `FromRequestParts`.

I also want to extract body into Json but don't know how to do it

Comment: Why are you implementing `Handler` by hand on a struct? Per the trait doc: "You shouldn’t need to depend on this trait directly. It is automatically implemented to closures of the right types.", and `axum::handler` describes them as "async functions that can be used to handle requests". What purpose is there to willfully shoving your foot in a meat grinder? Just make "server" your application state and take that from the handler.

Comment: I try to implement a microservices application. Several microservices will implement the same Server struct which resolves the context ans handle errors and responses and just pass its own RpcHandler to the server struct. I want an abstract server I can use in several crates of the workspace